# Finding a fragment in the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

What's the best way to find if a particular fragment is present on the fragment `backstack`?
Currently, i loop through and use the fragment class name to see if there is one present.
Was wondering if i could query the `FragmentManger` in an efficient manner.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

yes you can find fragment by tagname.but before that you have to set that tag name and it should be unique.

```html
String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
  String fragmentTag = backStateName;

  FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = manager
    .popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
```

here is the complete code it is a method  that add the fragment to backstack and find it.

```html
// For the Fragment Replace And AddtobackStack
 void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
  String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
  String fragmentTag = backStateName;

  FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
  boolean fragmentPopped = manager
    .popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

  if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
   // fragment not in back stack, create it.
   FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

   ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
   ft.commit();

  }
```

Comment: this seems to be a better idea. i will accept the answer after testing it. thanks a lot. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this,

The FragmentManager has methods:

```
getBackStackEntryCount()
getBackStackEntryAt (int index)
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
 Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId());
}
```

Comment: That's precisely what i am doing now. That's what i meant by looping through. Thanks for your answer. Do you have a better way to do this without the need for the `for()` loop?